# Asserting that a JMockit expectation result is the same instance as constructed

Tags: java, junit, jmockit, hamcrest

Here is a much-stripped down method from real life... the real method does other things, but I've narrowed down some strange behaviour to just these few lines. Consider a method that tries to create a `java.sql.Timestamp` from a `java.util.Date`... (never mind if I'm doing something wrong in this method; that's not the point):

```
public class MyTest {

    public Timestamp convertDateToTimestamp(Date d) {
        long l = d.getTime();
        Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(l);
        return ts;
    }

}
```

So I write the following JMockit JUnit test case for this method:

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class MyTestTest {

    @Tested MyTest test;

    @Test
    public void testConvertDateToTimestamp(@Mocked final Timestamp ts, @Mocked final Date d) throws Exception {
        new Expectations() {
            {
                d.getTime(); result = 8675309l;
                new Timestamp(8675309l); result = ts;
            }
        };

         Timestamp retval = test.convertDateToTimestamp(d);
         assertThat(retval, sameInstance(ts));
    }

}
```

Note the assertion in the last line there ... I thought I should be certain I'm getting the exact same instance that my constructor created.

This test returns a very peculiar result:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: sameInstance(<java.sql.Timestamp@6e3c1e69>)
     but: was <java.sql.Timestamp@6e3c1e69>
    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
    at com.example.dcohl.MyTestTest.testConvertDateToTimestamp(MyTestTest.java:32)
...
```

Can anybody explain this? My assertion is failing because it was expecting one instance of `Timestamp` but instead it got ... that exact same instance of `Timestamp`?

Now, if I check for equality, using `is(ts)` instead of `sameInstance(ts)`, my test succeeds. And it's not critical the be the same object; equality will suffice. But this is a head-scratching result...

Comment: By using a debugger one can see that `retval` and `ts` are two different objects although the `toString` method produces the same string for both.

Answer (score 0):

When a test records a constructor expectation such as `new Timestamp(8675309l); result = ts;`, it only means that future `Timestamp` instances created through matching constructor invocations will be logically equivalent to the `ts` mock instance (ie, they will have the same mock behavior as recorded/verified on `ts`). It does not mean they will be the same instance; they will still be new instances.

Comment: So is there a way to assure that I am passing that newly-constructed `Timestamp` and not a `Timestamp` derived from some other source?

Comment: Yes: call `convertDateToTimestamp` two times from the test, passing the same `Date`, and check the returned references point to different instances.